# R: How to read in file and skip lines that have errors with fread function?

Tags: r, error-handling, data.table

I'm trying to read in a CSV file with fread function but while reading it breaks cause of extra characters in the row. So I was wondering if there is a way to read the file, skip the rows with errors, and continue reading it? Thank you for any advice.
Below, you can see the error I get

In fread("data.csv",  :
Stopped early on line 617854. Expected 52 fields but found 54. Consider fill=TRUE and comment.char=. First discarded non-empty line:

Comment: Did you try the recommended arguments that the error message suggests?

Comment: But for several reasons, I think the answer to your question is "no", there is not a way to have `fread` skip problematic rows and continue reading. I hope somebody else knows a way to prove me wrong here, ...

Comment: yes I tried the error message suggestions but no luck, do you know any other workaround for this? the file is really big (around 10gb) that is why I'm using fread function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the `nrows` and `skip` arguments of `fread` to kind of do this yourself. I haven't got an appropriately broken csv to hand to test this on so no promises that this will work, but maybe something like the stuff below. This is basically an attempt to automate taking that row number flagged in the warning, and resuming reading the csv in for all rows *after* that row.

Essentially I'm reading in 100,000 rows at a time, and if that's successful, I write that data to a `list` called `data_chunks`. If it throws a warning, I pick up the warning message, use some regex to figure out what the line number is, and read up to that line. I then return that `data.table` and write to the `data_chunks` list. I then update the `rows_to_skip` value by the number of rows across all my `data.table`s in `data_chunks`, plus the number of problem rows (I return a `bad_row` boolean along with the `data.table` to indicate this, and add it to `bad_rows` at each iteration).

It is all in a `while` loop so will keep executing until the number of `rows_to_skip` exceeds the number of rows to be read, in which case, an error is thrown and the `if` statement triggers the `break`, and you exit the loop. Finally, use `rbindlist` to bind all the rows together across your list. This feels pretty hacky and probably isn't all that reliable but for the sake of getting your data loaded into R it may be a start at least:

```
data_chunks <- list()
i <- 1
rows_to_skip <- 0
rows_to_read <- 100000
bad_rows <- 0
file_name <- "my.csv"

while (TRUE) {
  
  out <- tryCatch(
    list(
      data = data.table::fread(file_name, nrows = rows_to_read, skip = rows_to_skip, header = FALSE),
      bad_row = FALSE
    ),
    error = function(e) {
      e
    },
    warning = function(w) {
      warn_msg <- conditionMessage(w)
      warn_matches <- regexec("line (\\d+)", warn_msg)
      rows_to_read <- as.numeric(regmatches(warn_msg, warn_matches)[[1]][2]) - 1
      if (!is.na(rows_to_read)) {
        list(
          data = data.table::fread(file_name, nrows = rows_to_read, skip = rows_to_skip, header = FALSE),
          bad_row = TRUE
        )
      } else {
        NULL
      }
    })
  
  if ("error" %in% class(out) || is.null(out)) {
    break
  } else {
    data_chunks[[i]] <- out[["data"]]
  }

  bad_rows <- bad_rows + out[["bad_row"]]
  rows_to_skip <- sum(sapply(data_chunks, nrow)) + bad_rows
  i <- i + 1
  
}

mydata <- data.table::rbindlist(data_chunks, use.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you so much, after couple of adjustments works just right